# Numerical data from simulink to arduino uno

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink, arduino-uno

I want to send numerical data from Simulink to an Arduino Uno.

Because I don't know how to make it work in Simulink so I'm just trying with Matlab.

This code sends numerical data as `char`. So one character at a time to the Arduino. After that, I have to concatenate characters to construct the numerical value and then give it to the Arduino to treat. Then send it back to Matlab with the same way.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to send the numerical data as numeric to the Arduino, and send it back to Matlab/simulink as a numerical data.

This is the code I'm using in Matlab :

```
close all; clear all ;  clc;
delete (instrfind({'Port'},{'COM5'}))

s = serial('COM5');

set(s,'DataBits',8);
set(s,'StopBits',1);
set(s,'BaudRate',4800);
set(s,'Parity','none');

fopen(s)

while (1)
    if  (s.BytesAvailable)
        readData=fscanf(s)
    else
        fprintf(s,'arduino');
    end
end

fclose(s)
```

And this is the code I'm using in Arduino :

```
int sensorPin = A0;  
int sensorValue = 0; 
char incomingData;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(4800);
}

void loop() {

    if (Serial.available() > 0) 
    {
      incomingData = Serial.read(); //read incoming data
      Serial.println(incomingData);
      delay(100);
    }
    else {

      sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
      Serial.println(sensorValue);    
      delay(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already ask the question above. And now I found the answer, so I wanted to share it with you.

First, you have to close all communications with the Serial port, and initialise the values of the communication. You do that this way.

```
close all ;  clc;
delete (instrfind({'Port'},{'COM3'}))
s = serial('COM3');
set(s,'DataBits',8);
set(s,'StopBits',1);
set(s,'BaudRate',9600);
set(s,'Parity','none');
```

Remarque : Not all the time you have the 'COM3' port, so you have to see in your Arduino which port you are using. Also, you have to make the exacte value of "BaudRate" in matlab and in the Arduino too.

Second, you send the float number, then you read it this way :

```
YourValue = 123.456; % This is just an exemple
while (1)
    fprintf(s,'%f',YourValue);  % sendig the value to the Arduino
    readData=fscanf(s,'%f')     % receiving the value from the Arduino and printing it
end
fclose(s)
```

Now, for the Arduino part, it is simple. The code is presented as below :

```
int sensorPin = A0;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor
float incomingData;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  if (Serial.available()) 
  {
    incomingData = Serial.parseFloat(); //read incoming data
    delay(100);
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println(incomingData);
    delay(100);
  }
}
```

Remarque : When I send many values from matlab to the Arduino, then I send them back to matlab. I have the first value always is printed this way [] or this way 0. I don't know what the problem is.

Thanks for all of you !!